# Tight asymptotic upper bound for T(n)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

[image]

I don't really have idea to solve this question

also another question is
 what about
T(n)=n/n+ n/n+1 + n/n+2+ ... + n/n^2
I try log and get about theta( logn+log(n+1) ) but how can I transoform it back to the answer

Comment: What are you actually asking?  Your question starts with 'also'.

Comment: So sorry for my poor English.
It's about two questions.
first one I really dont know how to solve it.
and second one I try that way(with log),but still can't solve it.